# How to get all classes from a package in a different project without dependency?

Tags: java, class, package, circular-dependency

I have 2 projects:

ProjectA, ProjectB

From ProjectA I want to write a code to get all the classes inside ProjectB's package `mypackage`

Without adding ProjectB to ProjectA's classpath is it possible?

ProjectA is already in ProjectB classpath so I don't want to create circular dependency.

Comment: Without using maven or gradle, I think you should handle it by your own and write maven task to do it for you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a web service that implements your methods and classes etc.. (project A). Then import it in your project B , this will let you use methods from from project A  without cross path those projects , just by link to web service application . Hope helps !